# postgreSQL installation from graphical installed

Tags: 12.04, installation, postgresql

I tried to install postgreSQL on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I have version pgsql9.1 on my windows machine and wanted to make both installation the same with the same components.

I downloaded `postgresql-9.1.6-1-linux-x64.run` on my ubuntu but it does not want to start with package manager, I got this error:

```
The file “/home/Downloads/postgresql-9.1.6-1-linux-x64.run” could not be opened.
```

I thought it should go automatically with package manager or just run by itself. Is there a way to install this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the permission of the file and make it as a executable.

Open terminal and type:

```
chmod +x postgresql-9.1.6-1-linux-x64.run
```

To install the package as a root user, use

```
sudo ./postgresql-9.1.6-1-linux-x64.run
```

Hope this helps.